# File Not Found error when trying to open .tif file

Tags: python, raster, netcdf4, rasterio

I am trying to open a .tif raster file for my project, but Python can't seem to find it on my computer. I am using Mac OS.

This is the code:

```
import netCDF4 as nc

rasterfile = ('~/Desktop/sds cw/tx_ens_mean_0.25deg_reg_2011-2021_v24.0e.nc')
rasterdata = nc.Dataset(rasterfile)
```

This is the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Desktop/sds cw/tx_ens_mean_0.25deg_reg_2011-2021_v24.0e.nc'
```

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expand the path.

```
import pathlib
path = pathlib.Path('~/Desktop/sds cw/tx_ens_mean_0.25deg_reg_2011-2021_v24.0e.nc')
rasterdata = nc.Dataset(path.expanduser())
```